# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.(jwt authentication)

Tags: mysql, node.js, jwt

I am new nodejs. I can't redirect to a protected page after sending jwt. Here what I am trying to do is after getting user details from the database, I am creating a jwt. But after that I want to redirect to a protected page.

```js
app.post('/Signin', function (req, res){
 var post = req.body;
 var sql = "SELECT id,name FROM `users` WHERE `name`='"+post.uname+"'and`password`='"+post.pass+"'";
 con.query(sql,function(err,result,col){
  if(result.length)
  {
   var re = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
   var token = jwt.sign(re,'ssshhh',{expiresIn : 1440});
   res.json({
           error: false,
            message: 'Validation successful!',
           token: token
        });
   console.log("Successful login");
   res.redirect("Protected");
  }
  else
  {
  console.log("Wrong Details");
  res.redirect("Signin");
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirects send a GET request.  This is controlled by the browser.  The browser will not automatically add the Authorization: Bear token header to the request (causing failure of page).

Typically, for redirect, you need to load security details into a cookie (e.g. put the JWT token into a cookie and have the protected page pull from the cookie)